# error C2061: syntax error : identifier '_bstr_t'

Tags: c++, bstr

Code:

```
     virtual void DeleteItem(_bstr_t ItemName) = 0
```

Error:

```
      error C2061: syntax error : identifier '_bstr_t'
```

i tried google online and use #include  but it doesnt remove the error

any other way to resolve this?

Comment: What are your #includes?

Comment: [This page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zthfhkd6.aspx) says you should `#include <comutil.h>` - if that's not working for you, try `cl /E` to see preprocessor output, and see if you can see either `_bstr_t` defined or some `#ifdef` branch that bypasses it.

Answer (score 0):

Add `#include <comdef.h>`(where `_bstr_t` definition included) to your include file, for example `stdafx.h`.